# C++ Array increment of individual elements

Tags: c++, arrays

hi i am trying to print the following table using arrays
the first column contains the rating for the movie and the second contains the number of people who rated 1, 2, 3, etc.

```
i[rating]             sum_rating[number of people who have rated 1, 2, 3 and so on]                   
1                     3
2                     2
3                     4
4                     1
5                     6
```

heres what i have tried so far

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {

int reviewNum, i, j;
int rating[250], sum_rating[250];

cout << "Enter the number of reviews" << endl;
cin >> reviewNum;

cout << "Enter ratings " << endl;
for (i = 0; i < reviewNum; i++ ) {
  cin>> rating[i];
}

for ( i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
sum_rating[i] = 0;

for (int i=0; i< reviewNum; i++){
    for(int j=0; j <=5; j++){
        if(rating[i]==j){
            sum_rating[i] += 1;
        }
    }
 }

cout << "Rating \t Number of people \n";
for ( i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
  cout << "   " << i+1 << " \t\t" << sum_rating[i] << endl;

return 0;
}
```

i am somehow getting incorrect output for this program, and my ide is not showing any errors. can someone please explain where its going wrong?

Comment: please provide the actual output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary error is in the loop wherein you compute the statistics:

```
for (int i=0; i< reviewNum; i++){
    for(int j=0; j <=5; j++){
        if(rating[i]==j){
            sum_rating[i] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

With the structure and indexing as you present, you should be incrementing `sum_rating[j]`, not `sum_rating[i]`.  Of course, part of the problem is that you've made that too complicated.  It would be better to avoid the inner loop altogether by simply doing this:

```
for (int i=0; i< reviewNum; i++){
    sum_rating[rating[i]] += 1;
}
```

You also seem a bit inconsistent about whether ratings go from 1 to 5 or 1 to 6, and you perform no validation of your inputs, but those issues are comparatively minor.

Comment: thanks a lot bro.. was trying to figure this out for almost 2 days!